# Unable to programmatically place a UIButton using anchor points with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a programmatically generated UIButton that I wish to place at the bottom of the screen so it appears like this.

[image]

I am using the following code to attempt this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Button", comment: "Button"), for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .green
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)

    let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
    button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
}

@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    print("Button pushed")
}
```

However, this gives me the following error:

> 2016-10-19 11:58:11.404034 ButtonApp[13462:8670705]
>   [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. ...
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active)>",
>       "
>   (active, names: '|':UIWindow:0x7983c1f0 )>",
>       "UILayoutGuide:0x79e44030'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'
>   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x79e3f8b0 )>" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> ...
>
> ```
> "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x79e339f0 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79e3f5d0'Button'.midX == 0   (active)>",
> "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x79e40d60 h=--& v=--& UIButton:0x79e3f5d0'Button'.width == 0   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x78632c30 UIButton:0x79e3f5d0'Button'.trailing ==
> ```
>
> UILayoutGuide:0x79e44030'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing
>   (active)>",
>       "
>   (active, names: '|':UIWindow:0x7983c1f0 )>",
>       "UILayoutGuide:0x79e44030'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'
>   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x79e3f8b0 )>" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
>   
>   (active)>
>
> ... (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x79e3f8b0 )>",
>       "
>   (active, names: '|':UIWindow:0x7983c1f0 )>",
>       "
>   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x79e3f8b0 )>" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> ...

Comment: did you define constraints for the view that is containing the button?

Comment: You need to do `button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: @ReinierMelian No, I am testing this inside an empty app with nothing other than the code you see. However, I did create a new view with constraints and re-tested with the same results.

Comment: @dan That worked, thanks. If you want to submit that as the answer, I'll mark it as correct. Annoyed that it was not mentioned on the official Apple page  though it has not been updated for Swift 3.0.